# How to get key and append it to next value in json file?

Tags: javascript, json

My scenario is like this :

```
var data = { 
    name : 'joe',
    message : 'Welcome ' + name,
    fullname : 'Mr. ' + name
};
```

Expected Output :

```
console.log(' user : ' + data.message)
Welcome joe
```

How to do this ?

Comment: Voting to close as your question is unclear. `message : 'Welcome ' + name,` is invalid unless you have declared `name` beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

The probably closest approach would be to use functions as parameters.

```js
const data = {
   name: 'Joe',
   message: function() {
      return `Welcome ${this.name}`;
   }
}

console.log(data.message())
```

However, keep in mind that this does not work for native JSON objects, only for JS objects.

Comment: I originally wanted to use the ${} syntax, but decided not to because the author used string concatenation. It doesn't really matter in this scenario if backticks or "/' are used anyway.

Comment: @Ivan They are called [`Template Literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It was introduced in `ES6`.

Comment: @LukasBach, yes,  Its correct , its working fine , it wanted like this only.  Thanks

Comment: Yeah @Ivan they are

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function getter inside an object using [`get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and then call it as a `property`.

```js
var data = { 
  name : 'joe',
  message : 'Welcome ',
  name : 'Mr. ',
  get fullMessage() {
    return this.message + this.name;
  }
};

console.log(data.fullMessage);
```

Comment: Wait @Ivan I just pressed accept, why have you edited it like so?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace message and fullname string by functions like this :

```
var data = { 
    name : 'joe',
    message : function() { return 'Welcome ' + this.name },
    fullname : function() { return 'Mr. ' + this.name }
}

console.log(data.message())
console.log(data.fullname())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the initialization of the variable, you can do it using functions. Example:

```js
var data = { 
    name : 'joe',
    message: function(){
     return 'Welcome ' + this.name;
    },
    fullname: function(){
     return 'Mr. ' + this.name;
    }
}

console.log('user : ' + data.message());
console.log('user : ' + data.fullname());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getter`s:

```js
var data = { 
    name : 'joe',
    get message() { return `Welcome ${this.name}`; },
    get fullname() { return `Mr. ${this.name}`; },
};

console.log(data.message);
console.log(data.fullname);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use external variable of your jSON object.
Try :

```js
var name = "joe";
var data = { 
        name : name,
        message : 'Welcome ' + name,
        fullname : 'Mr. ' + name
    };
    
console.log(' user : ' + data.message);
```